# Where can I find information on hid-generic error codes?

Tags: kernel, usb, kernel-modules

I am writing some firmware for a microcontroller that communicates over USB. I am getting this error from `dmesg`:

```
[3034764.122150] hid-generic 0003:16C0:27DB.0015: item fetching failed at offset -1080905469
[3034764.122158] hid-generic: probe of 0003:16C0:27DB.0015 failed with error -22
```

Does this error come from the kernel or userspace? Where can I find out what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from the kernel driver. If you go to the kernel sources web site freetext search [lxr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/search), and enter the search string you will find it leads you to the file [hid/hid-core.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-core.c#L1033)

```
1033 hid_err(device, "item fetching failed at offset %d\n", (int)(end - start));
```

Comment: Ah, thank-you, my google fu was not good enough this time.